# I can't run an email program built by cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, cx-freeze, smtplib

I have a program that runs perfectly as a Python program. I try to build it will cx_Freeze however, and I get an error when I get up to the part of the program that emails. `No SSL support included in this Python`.

I have smtplib in my setup.py, as well as all other email-related modules.

```py
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import os
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

packages = ["smtplib"]
include_files = [(os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll')),
                 (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll')),
                ".env", "message.txt"]

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [
    Executable('boxes.py', base=base, targetName = "SuperbowlBoxesGenerator.exe", icon="icon.ico", copyright="MIT", trademarks="CompuGenius Programs")
]

setup(name='Superbowl Boxes Generator',
      version = '2.0',
      description = 'An automated generator for the betting game Superbowl Boxes.',
      author = "CompuGenius Programs",
      options={'build_exe': {'include_files': include_files, 'packages': packages}},
      executables=executables)
```

This is my setup.py script.

Someone please help me. This program is for my dad's birthday, and it's already overdue due to the fact that the files got deleted from my computer, and I had to rewrite everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ssl` to packages, and

```py
os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll'),
os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'libssl-1_1-x64.dll'),
```

to include_files. This is your revised setup.py.

```py
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import os
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

packages = ["smtplib", "ssl"]
include_files = [(os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll')),
                 (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll')),
                 os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll'),
                 os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'libssl-1_1-x64.dll'),
                ".env", "message.txt"]

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [
    Executable('boxes.py', base=base, targetName = "SuperbowlBoxesGenerator.exe", icon="icon.ico", copyright="MIT", trademarks="CompuGenius Programs")
]

setup(name='Superbowl Boxes Generator',
      version = '2.0',
      description = 'An automated generator for the betting game Superbowl Boxes.',
      author = "CompuGenius Programs",
      author_email = "compugeniusprograms@gmail.com",
      options={'build_exe': {'include_files': include_files, 'packages': packages}},
      executables=executables)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked perfectly! Good on you mate!

Comment: Haha, no problem! Happy coding!